Cannot index into a value of type `std::fs::ReadDir`
I'm trying to get the path to the first entry in a directory, but it seems the read_dir response type ReadDir is an iterator and cannot be indexed, e.g.
fn get_single_file_or_none(dir_path: &PathBuf) -> Result<Option<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    let entries = fs::read_dir(dir_path)?;

    if entries.count() == 1 {
        let path = entries[0].path();
//                        ^^ cannot index into a value of type `std::fs::ReadDir`
        return Ok(path);
    }

    return Ok(None);
}

How can I get the path to the first (and in this case, the only) entry in the directory?
I cant start iterating over the entries, knowing there's only one, and return the first one I hit. Is that the only solution? e.g.
if entries.count() == 1 {
    for entry_res in entries {
        return match entry_res {
            Err(er) => Err(er),
            Ok(en) => Ok(Some(en.path())),
        };
    }
}


Your function name promises a file, but your function body does not check the entry actually is a file.

@cafce25 Thanks for highlighting. This was just a quick MRE to demonstrate the error. As you point out, the real implementation would want to check that the only entry is indeed a file.

itertools has the handy exactly_one() function:
use itertools::Itertools;

fn get_single_file_or_none(dir_path: &PathBuf) -> Result<Option<PathBuf>, io::Error> {
    let entries = fs::read_dir(dir_path)?;
    Ok(entries.exactly_one().ok().transpose()?.map(|it| it.path()))
}

This is more efficient than count(), since it will only read the directory once.

I like this solution as it's more in line with what I was trying to do. The implementation of exactly_one is pretty similar to what cdhowie wa suggesting in one of the other answers; call next() twice, ensure that the first returns Some and the second returns None

You can simply call next() once on the iterator to get the first entry, or None if there are no entries. There's no need to call count().
use std::{fs, io, path::PathBuf};

fn get_single_file_or_none(dir_path: &PathBuf) -> io::Result<Option<PathBuf>> {
    let mut entries = fs::read_dir(dir_path)?;

    if let Some(entry) = entries.next() {
        return Ok(Some(entry?.path()));
    }

    return Ok(None);
}

This could also be written in a more functional style, but due to the combination of Option and Result, it's not necessarily easier to understand...
use std::{fs, io, path::PathBuf};

fn get_single_file_or_none(dir_path: &PathBuf) -> io::Result<Option<PathBuf>> {
    fs::read_dir(dir_path)
        .and_then(|mut entries| entries.next().transpose())
        .map(|entry_opt| entry_opt.map(|entry| entry.path()))
}


Great, thanks! I was looking for a first() and never found one, but found a last() which I could also use for my scenario. Note that your solution deviates slightly from what I'm trying to achieve, which is to return the path to the only entry in the directory (or None, if there is not exactly one), so the count check is still needed.

@devklick You still don't want to use count() because that will read the whole iterator when you only need to know if there are 0, 1, or at least 2. Consider something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=20221ec8f164d059e1b9f10b60b61111

Francis, you are welcome to incorporate the code in the playground link in my comment into your answer. It's based on your first snippet, though with a few changes. (I fuse the iterator since ReadDir is not fused, and alter the logic so that 2+ elements will cause it to return None. The fuse call is so that if it would return None and then Some(Err(_)) it will instead return None and None.)
